# Search through list (JSON) SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I am currently doing Tutorials that are available on the Apple Developer website.

I was looking at the 'Handling User Input' part and I have a question. In there they take the JSON file and use it to populate the list. From there they create 'Favourite' toggle. My question is, is there a possibility to make JSON list searchable?

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites only")
                }

                ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkList()
            .environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```

I found a way of making search field, which would look something like this:

```
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

and then calling it, but I can't find a way to search through the list. I found a lot of tutorials showing how to search through array, but that isn't very helpful.
I tried few things, this is one of them, but it doesn't work:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Search")

                List(LandmarkData.filter{searchText == "" ? true : $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)}, id: \.self){ landmark in
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }

            }.navigationBarTitle("Landmarks")
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to it:

```
List {
    ForEach(LandmarkData.filter {
        $0.name.lowercased().contains(self.searchText) || self.searchText.isEmpty 
    }, id: \.self) { landmark in
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
    }
}
```

The rest of the code stayed the same :) Hope it will help somebody.